# Count throws for sixes in rolling dice python

Tags: python, loops, simulation, dice

For an introductionary course in Python I got an assignment to make a simulation for eolling dice

You want all of your dices (5 in total) to get the value six, and count how many throws in total it takes for a person to get all sixes. I need a loop that simulates this problem 100.000 times and then need to divide the total amount of counts by 100.000 to get the outcome. I know that the final outcome should be something around 13, but I am not getting that and I am not sure why.

I know something is wrong in my approach to this problem , but what?

```
import random

count1=0
count2=0
count3=0
count4=0
count5=0
loopcounter = 0

for loopcouter in range (1,100000):
    dice1=int( random.random()*6)+1
    if dice1 != 6:
        #reroll
        while dice1 != 6:
            dice1=int( random.random()*6)+1
            #set counter1
            count1 = count1+1
        else:
            count1 = 1

        dice2=int( random.random()*6)+1
        if dice2 != 6:
            #reroll while not six
            while dice2 != 6:
                dice2=int( random.random()*6)+1
                #set counter2
                count2 = count2+1
        else:
            count2 = 1

        dice3=int( random.random()*6)+1
        if dice3 != 6:
            #reroll while not six
            while dice3 != 6:
                dice3=int( random.random()*6)+1
                #set counter3
                count3 = count3+1
        else:
            count3 = 1
        dice4=int( random.random()*6)+1
        if dice4 != 6:
            #reroll while not six
            while dice4 != 6:
                dice4=int( random.random()*6)+1
                #set counter4
                count4 = count4+1
        else:
            count4 = 1

        dice5=int( random.random()*6)+1
        if dice5 != 6:
            #reroll while not six
            while dice5 != 6:
                dice5=int( random.random()*6)+1
                #set counter5
                count5 = count5+1
        else:
            count5 = 1


    #print (dice1)
    print (count1)

#print (dice2)
print (count2)
#print (dice3)
print (count3)
#print (dice4)
print (count4)
#print (dice5)
print (count5)

allcount = count1+count2+count3+count4+count5
averagecount = int(allcount / 100000)

print ("the total number of throws is",allcount)
print ("the average number of throws is",averagecount)
```

So, if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong, that would be perfect!

Comment: Could you clarify if you want to always have throws of 5 dices at a time or reroll every roll until it is a 6

Comment: In the classic game of yahtzee you only get 3 rolls to get a 6, but you are giving them unlimited rolls, and if you don't get 5 6's then that go would be a fail. The chance of a specific yahtzee is 1.33% so, you would expect a result of 0.013 when you divide by 100000.

Comment: You initial if condition means if you throw a 6 no other dice a rolled, in fact none of the if conditions are necessary.

Comment: Please do not vandalise your question; you cannot invalidate the work others have put into answering you.

Answer (score 2):

According to the instructions you need the maximum of count for each round as this will tell you how many rolls you needed to get all 6s.
This is a re-write of your code using a loop for each dice:

```
import random

allcount = 0
for loopcouter in range(100000):   # 1,100000 would only loop 99999 times
    count = [0]*5
    for i in range(5):             # 5 dice
        while True:
            dice = random.randint(1,6)  # Use randint
            count[i] += 1
            if dice == 6:
                break
    allcount += max(count)         # The number of rolls needed to get all 6s

averagecount = allcount // 100000

print("the total number of throws is", allcount)
print("the average number of throws is", averagecount)
```

And this seems to average in 12/13 range.

There are many ways to solve this for example you can use `iter` and an anonymous function `lambda` to replace the inner while loop. These start to use more advanced features of python (iterators and generators):

```
from random import randint

allcount = 0
for _ in range(100000):
    counts = [1]*5
    for i in range(5):
        dice = list(iter(lambda: randint(1,6), 6))
        counts[i] += len(dice)
    allcount += max(counts)
averagecount = allcount // 100000
```

In fact you can completely collapse this into one line of code but it gets increasingly harder to read and breaks all sorts of manner of style:

```
allcount = sum(max((1 + sum(1 for _ in iter(lambda: randint(1, 6), 6)))
                   for _ in range(5)) for _ in range(100000))
averagecount = allcount // 100000
```

Comment: You summed up all the rolls for all the dice. For each round you just needed the worst number (max) of the rolls for all the dice. The if conditions arbitrarily reset the counters to 1 if you happened to roll a 6 in the first roll for a round - this should have been += 1 because it was a running counter. Removing the if conditions actually improved the code but you were counting too much.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very different approach.

Let's make an object, die, that will roll until it hits the target:

```
import random

class die(object):
    def __init__(self, sides=6):
        self.sides=sides
        self.count=0

    def roll(self):
        self.count+=1
        return random.randint(1,self.sides)    

    def roll_until(self, tgt, giveup=100000):
        result=0
        self.tgt=tgt
        while result!=tgt and self.count<giveup:
            result=self.roll()
        if self.count<giveup:
            return self.count
```

Then you can just create an instance of that (a single die) and tell it to roll itself until a target is hit:

```
>>> d=die()
>>> d.roll_until(6)
2
>>> d.tgt
6
>>> d.count
2
```

`2` is the number of times d needed to be rolled until `6` is the result with a 6 sided die.

Why do it this way? Now you can easily create a list of die:

```
>>> dice=[die().roll_until(6) for i in range(6)]
>>> dice
[15, 3, 3, 4, 5, 2]
```

And easily answer your questions.

Take the max of this list:

```
>>> max(die().roll_until(6) for i in range(6))
9
```

`n` times divided by `float(n)` for the result:

```
>>> n=100000
>>> sum(max(die().roll_until(6) for i in range(6)) for i in range(n))/float(n)
13.95879
```

---

Whoops! Only five dice in a game of Yatzee. Easy change:

```
>>> sum(max(die().roll_until(6) for i in range(5)) for i in range(n))/float(n)
13.0032
```

Comment: FYI: There are only 5 dice in a game of yahtzee.

Comment: Easy change! `>>> sum(max(die().roll_until() for i in range(5)) for i in range(n))/float(n)
13.0032`

Answer (score 0):

With your new edit, the counts should still start with `0` but you should also increase your counters once before you go into the while loop, because this already marks one roll.

Also, you should use a different function to determine your random integer. Instead of using

```
(random.random() * 6) + 1
```

use:

```
random.randint(1,6)
```